# RSA encryption in Android ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, android, exception, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

i am trying to do RSA encryption on Android, i followed the guide on RSA from here: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/rsa_encryption.shtml

i modified the code a bit, and here is my code:

```
Button GenKey = null;
Button encryptString = null;
Button decryptString = null;
EditText plainField = null;
EditText encryptedField = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    GenKey = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGenKey);
    GenKey.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
                generateKey();
        }
    });

    encryptString = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEncrypt);
    encryptString.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            byte[] encryptedData = null;
            byte[] dataToEncrypt = null;
            plainField = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.eTxtPlainTxt);
            String plainText = plainField.getText().toString();
                dataToEncrypt = plainText.getBytes("UTF-8");
                encryptedData = rsaEncrypt(dataToEncrypt);              
            String encryptedText=null;
                encryptedText = new String(encryptedData, "UTF-8");
            encryptedField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eTxtCiphTxt);
            encryptedField.setText(encryptedText);
        }
    });

    decryptString = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDecrypt);
    decryptString.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            byte[] decryptedData = null;
            byte[] dataToEncrypt = null;
            encryptedField = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.eTxtCiphTxt);
            String cipherText = encryptedField.getText().toString();    
                dataToEncrypt = cipherText.getBytes("UTF-8");
                decryptedData = rsaDecrypt(dataToEncrypt);

            String decryptedText = null;
                decryptedText = new String(decryptedData,"UTF-8");
            plainField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eTxtPlainTxt);
            plainField.setText(decryptedText);
        }
    });

}//end of onCreate

public void generateKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, IOException{
    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kpg.initialize(512);
    KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();

    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    RSAPublicKeySpec pub = fact.getKeySpec(kp.getPublic(), RSAPublicKeySpec.class);
    RSAPrivateKeySpec priv = fact.getKeySpec(kp.getPrivate(), RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);

    saveToFile("public.key", pub.getModulus(),pub.getPublicExponent());
    saveToFile("private.key", priv.getModulus(),priv.getPrivateExponent());
    }//end of generateKey

public void saveToFile(String fileName, BigInteger mod, BigInteger exp) throws IOException {        
    FileOutputStream fOutStream = openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fOutStream));
    oos.writeObject(mod);
    oos.writeObject(exp);
    oos.flush();
    oos.close();
    }//end of saveToFile

public PublicKey readPubKeyFromFile(String keyFileName) throws StreamCorruptedException, IOException{
    FileInputStream fInStream = openFileInput(keyFileName);
    ObjectInputStream oInStream = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fInStream));
        BigInteger m = (BigInteger) oInStream.readObject();
        BigInteger e = (BigInteger) oInStream.readObject();
        RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(m, e);
        KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey pubKey = fact.generatePublic(keySpec);
        return pubKey;
        oInStream.close();
}//end of readPubKeyFromFile

public PrivateKey readPrivKeyFromFile(String keyFileName) throws StreamCorruptedException, IOException{
    FileInputStream fInStream = openFileInput(keyFileName);
    ObjectInputStream oInStream = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fInStream));
        BigInteger m = (BigInteger) oInStream.readObject();
        BigInteger e = (BigInteger) oInStream.readObject();
        RSAPrivateKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(m, e);
        KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PrivateKey privKey = fact.generatePrivate(keySpec);
        return privKey;
        oInStream.close();
}//end of readPubKeyFromFile

public byte[] rsaEncrypt(byte[] data) throws StreamCorruptedException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    PublicKey pubKey = readPubKeyFromFile("public.key");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
    byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(data);
    return cipherData;    
}//end of rsaEncrypt

public byte[] rsaDecrypt(byte[] data) throws StreamCorruptedException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException{
    PrivateKey privKey = readPrivKeyFromFile("private.key");
    Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey);
    byte[] plainData = decipher.doFinal(data);
    return plainData;   
}
```

the problem is when i encrypt the string, it displays some random characters symbol such as €◊•¶⓿ etc...
another problem is, when i try to decrypt it, it throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at the doFinal on the decryption part..

where is the problem?

Comment: `encryptedText = new String(encryptedData, "UTF-8");` is a bug. String is not a container for arbitrary byte[] arrays. Also you cannot use RSA to encrypt arbitrarily long byte[]. It can only encrypt a small amount of data, the length of the modulus in bytes - 11.

Comment: so, how should i convert the byte array to String?

Comment: why do you want it to be a String? Can't you just keep it as a byte[]?

Comment: because i need to display the result in an editText view, and as far as i know it require a string to set the text.

Comment: Well, then there are a couple of options. Probably the most standard way is to encode the byte[] into a String using a base64 encoder. Another option to use a hex encoder.

Comment: thank you, mind pointing me to a correct way? i googled a bit, and it seems like i need to create another class, is this the right way?
and does it mean i need to do the String to byte[] conversion this way too?

Comment: Android seems to already have what you need [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html). And yes, you have to base64 decode to get back to a byte[] from your String.

Comment: thank you, will look into it, and you mentioned that RSA cant encrypt long  byte[]? what does this mean? i thought the modulus only affect the numbers of characters?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that only very short in length byte arrays can be operated on directly by RSA. In your case of a 512 bit modulus, it can only encrypt byte arrays of 64-11 = 53 bytes or less.

Comment: i made some changes using the Base64 class, here is the snippet:


`plainField = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.eTxtPlainTxt);

 String plainText = plainField.getText().toString();

 dataToEncrypt = Base64.encode(plainText.getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT);`

Comment: You were supposed to base64 encode the ciphertext, not the plaintext.

Comment: sorry, i was trying to edit the comment to make it more readable, took me too much time.

so, i can just pass the plaintext into the encyption function using `getBytes()`?

and my current code gave a `NoClassDefFoundError`, any idea what could cause it?

Comment: Yes, using getBytes`("UTF-8")`. I don't know what is causing the exception.